# Can't pass rspec tests after add Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm following the Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, and i'm on the part where you add a Bootstrap dropdown top nav bar to your app that changes depending on if the user is signed in or not.

This is the code that makes the nav bar change

```
<% if signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to 'Profile', current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Settings', '#' %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to 'Sign out', signout_path %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to 'Sign in', signin_path %></li>
      <% end %>
```

Now, i made the following rspec test

```
describe "with valid information" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }   

    before do
      visit '/signin'
      fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"
    end

    it { should have_title(user.name) }
    it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
end
```

After saving and reloading the app, i get everything working just fine.

But even though the app code itself it's working, the rspec tests are failing.

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication with valid information
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
       expected #has_link?("Sign out", {:href=>"/signout"}) to return true, got
false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <
top (required)>'

  2) Authentication with valid information
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user))
}
       expected #has_link?("Profile", {:href=>"/users/1"}) to return true, got f
alse
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in <
top (required)>'

  3) Authentication with valid information
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(user.name) }
       expected #has_title?("Michael Hartl") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:36:in `block (3 levels) in <
top (required)>'

  4) Authentication with valid information
     Failure/Error: it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
       expected #has_link?("Sign in", {:href=>"/signin"}) to return false, got t
rue
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <
top (required)>'
```

---

It says that the links ("coincidently" the ones nested in the dropdown menu) aren't returning true.

The paths on the rspec specs are the same ones used on the app code, and you can see that the app is redirecting you using the same paths/links described in rspec.

So what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I think, your spec is not able to find your links in bootstrap dropdown menu. I think, you just have to click that dropdown first than, it will be able to find that links. try with this :

```
describe "with valid information" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }   

    before do
      visit '/signin'
      fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"
    end

    click_link "Account"

    it { should have_title(user.name) }
    it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
 it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user), visible: false) }
```

Or

```
describe "with valid information", js: true do
  # before
  click_link "Account"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer which works for me here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833789/sign-out-rspec-test-failing-in-rails-tutorial-section-9-1-1

The relevant part:

> Thinking I needed to be validly signed in prior to changing my profile, I added this to my **user_pages_spec.rb**

```
context "edit" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { sign_in user }  <------------
before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
```